# Как постоянно добавлять данные в последнюю строку в таблице BD Room Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Есть таблица со списком городов которые выбирал пользователь

```
@Entity
class LastChosenCitiesEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val cityId: Int,
    val city: String,
    val country: String
)
```

У каждого города есть свой уникальный числовой id, и этот id  я обозначил как @PrimaryKey. Мне нужно чтоб каждое новое добавление данных в таблицу добавлялось всегда в последнюю строку, а получается данные автоматически сортируются по возрастанию id.

Нужно чтоб было вот так:

```
   id
    3
   11
    8
```

и я хочу добавить данные где id = 6

Нужно чтоб получилось вот так

```
  id
   3
  11
   8
   6
```

а получается вот так

```
   id
    3
    6
    8
   11
```

Как добавлять данные в последнюю строку не зависимо от id?

Comment: В базах данных вообще нет такого понятия, как последняя строка. Данные в выборке упорядочиваются по параметру сортировки, по умолчанию сортировка производится по ID записи. Вы можете указать любое другое поле таблицы для сортировки выборки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавлять новое поле, которое как раз будет отвечать за положение в списке.

```
@Entity
class LastChosenCitiesEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val listId: Int,
    @PrimaryKey
    val cityId: Int,
    val city: String,
    val country: String
)
```

Далее сортируйте по `listId`

Comment: Я так и сделал. Думал может можно обойтись без дополнительного поля. Спасибо